# How to add a key to an object, with an array value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was asked to add a key (named interests) to an object (named myObject). the key must have an array value. here i post the code. but it is not working.

```
var interests=[];
var myObject = {
  name: 'Eduardo',
  type: 'Most excellent',

  // Add your code here!
  interests:'reading',
  interests:'singing'
};
```

Comment: `interests: ['reading', 'singing']`, or if you want to add something to the object: `myObject.interests = ['reading', 'singing']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var interests = [];
var myObject = {
    name: 'Eduardo',
    type: 'Most excellent',
    interests: ['reading', 'singing']
};
```

or if you're trying to use the array already created:

```
var interests = ['reading', 'singing'];
var myObject = {
    name: 'Eduardo',
    type: 'Most excellent',
    interests: interests
};
```

or to add it after myObject has been created:

```
var myObject = {
    name: 'Eduardo',
    type: 'Most excellent'
};
myObject.interests = interests;
```